# Nexus S battery drains after updating to 4.2.2 even if turned off

Tags: updates, 4.2-jelly-bean, battery

My Google Nexus S battery drains after updating from 2.3.7 to 4.2.2, even if it is turned off. One night I shut it off at 70% charge, and when I turned it on in the morning it was at 9 or 10%. I bought a new battery but it has the same problem. What should I do?

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem to me.

Answer (score 2):

You should calibrate your battery:

1. Fully discharge your phone
2. Fully charge it when it is turned **off**
3. Disconnect charger and wait a minute
4. Connect it again and turn your phone on
5. Delete your data/system/batterystats.bin file (with [battery calibration](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nema.batterycalibration) for instance)
6. Reboot your device and disconnect charger

Also, it is [common problem](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/mobile/1puqNR70rGM/Wp_G7MtkXVsJ), so try to google it yourself

Hope this will solve it for you